# Visual studio 2010 setup project creation issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, windows-installer

I have two MSIs created using MS Visual Studio 2010.
Both MSIs created using same codebase, however, different Product Code and Upgrade Code.

Problem is once I uninstall the first application and try to open the second application from the shortcut exist in the start menu, it start the re-installation process.

Furthermore, If I check the actual installation folder of the second application in Program Files, all binaries exist and if I click on the Main Application EXE from there, it opens the second application without any issue.

Concern here is how to avoid re-installation process of the second application when I click on the shortcut exist in the start menu after un-installing the first application? Whats the relationship?

Comment: Does the reinstall happen on every run? Do the MSIs install shared components/registry entries/etc.?

Comment: At the first time it ask for re-installation. After continuing the installation application start properly. Also there is not specific registry entries written by the installer. However, there are shared assemblies written to the GAC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly not a re-installation process - it's a repair. There should be some MSIInstaller Application Event Log entries that say what appears to be missing. Perhaps there are some common files between the two separate MSI setups? If so, it seems that they are not shared properly. When you uninstalled that first product it removed something that is in use by the second product, so when you used a shortcut is repaired it. It doesn't need to be a file overlap - it could be a registry entry.

Comment: Correct. Application Event log says correctly. There were some common files. Thanks.